Installing Linux OS on Snapdragon 865 XR DEV board with SOM included
I have a Open-Q™ 865 Development Kit (SOM INCLUDED) and I want to put Linux OS on it as it seems the kernel image is now available as per mail:

Lantronix is pleased to announce the release of new and improved Open-Q™ 5165RB SOM Application firmware Ubuntu v2.0. This software release was tested on the Open-Q™ Dev Kit with Open-Q™ 5165RB SOM. This combination uses the SOM board QRB5165-SOM-A (8GB/128GB) and QRB5165-SOM-B (16GB/128GB), carrier board, power supply, optional LCD panel with touch and optional IMX258 camera board.


Can I add a Linux image instead of Android?

Will I face any issues with drivers or peripherals on the board?


I tried asking the question on Qualcomm dev forum but haven't got any response.
I have not tried installing Linux, but have a preinstalled android image.
Since it is an expensive hardware and there is a probability that I might brick my hardware, I do not want to take any chances.
